# Proving that $n$-cycle has order $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

I'm trying trying to prove that an $n$-cycle in some symmetric group has order $n$, but I don't know where to start. Would appreciate some hints.

Answer (score 1):

For each $n$-cycle $w$, it has a representation $(a_1a_2...a_n)$. $w^{n-1}(a_1)=a_{n}\neq a_1$ so $w$ has order at least $n$.

Comment: In $w^{n-1}(a_1)$, is $(a_1)$ an fixed permutation from $a_1$ to itself? I'm not quite sure how it comes about that $w^{n-1}(a_1)=a_{n-1}$.

Comment: Oh I see. $w^{n-1}(a_1)$ should be $a_n$

Comment: How can one show that $w^{n-1}(a_1)=a_n$? I'm somewhat confused.

Comment: $w$ by definition maps $a_i$ to $a_{i+1}$

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry I got confused with the notation a little bit.

Comment: Does your argument show that $w$ has order $n$ at least and order $n$ at most as well?

Comment: That cycle has order n and I showed it has order at least n.